# polynomials and maximum principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. For every $r>0$, let $M(r):=\max \{|P(z)| :|z|=r\}$. I want to show that the function $F(r)=\frac{M(r)}{r}$ is monotonically decreasing in $(0, +\infty)$.
Second question is: if $F(r_1)=F(r_2)$ for $r_1\neq r_2$, what can be said on polynomial $P$?

For the first question, how can i use maximum modulus principle? for the second, i have no idea....any help?

Comment: If $P(z) = z^n$, then $F(r) = r^{n-1}$ is not decreasing. Did you make a mistake in the definition of $F$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Domination of complex-value polynomial by highest power](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136410/domination-of-complex-value-polynomial-by-highest-power).

Comment: yes, there's an error. Put "increasing" in place of "decreasing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution: put $P(z)=z^nQ(\frac{1}{z})$. Then Q(z) is entire on $\mathbb C-{0}$. By maximum modulus principle, the function $M^Q(r)=max \{|Q(\frac{1}{z})|:|z|=r\}$ is increasing for $r>0$.

Now, $M(r)=r^nM^Q(r)$ and so $F(r)=r^{n-1}M^Q(r)$ is also increasing.
Did i make any mistake?