# An inequality on maximum of complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

let $p$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and let $t(r)=\max\{|p(z)|:|z|=r\}$. Show that $t(r)\geq t(s)$ is $0<r<s$. Equality holds iff $p(z)=z^n$.

Comment: Do you mean $t(r) \geq t(s)$ if $0 < s < r$ instead?

Comment: show that t(r)/r^n \geq t(s)/s^n,

Comment: This doesn't seem right. For large $|z|$, $p(z)$ is huge (and $|p(z)|$ increases rapidly), so I don't see how you would have $t(r)=t(s)$.

Comment: there was a typing error. correct question is show that $t(r)/r^n \geq t(s)/s^n$

Comment: This seems like it may be a duplicate of [Domination of complex-value polynomial by highest power](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136410/domination-of-complex-value-polynomial-by-highest-power)

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(z) = a_n z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$. Note that $t(r) = \max \limits _{|z| = r} \displaystyle \Bigg| \frac{p(z)}{z^n} \Bigg |$.

**Claim:** For every $r$, $t(r) \ge |a_n|$.

**Proof:** Use the Cauchy integral formula to write
$$
|a_n|
\le \frac{1}{2 \pi}  \Bigg|\int \limits_{|z| = r} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta ^{n+1}}\ \text{ }d\zeta \Bigg|
\le \frac{1}{2 \pi}  2 \pi r \max \limits _{|z| = r} \Bigg| \frac{p(z)}{z^{n+1}} \Bigg |
= \max \limits _{|z| = r} \Bigg| \frac{p(z)}{z^{n}} \Bigg | = t(r)
$$

Now that we have this the rest of the proof is easy.
 Now let $r < s < R$. The Maximum Modulus Theorem says that on the annulus $r \le |z| \le R$, the maximum modulus of $\displaystyle \frac{p(z)}{z^n}$ is attained on $|z| = r$ or $|z| = R$, for *all* $R > s$.

If $t(s) \gt t(r)$, then by the **Claim** we'd have $t(s) \gt |a_n|$. This is a contradiction because from $R$ large enough $t(s) > t(R)$, and so modulus of $\displaystyle \frac{p(z)}{z^n}$ does not take its maximum on the boundary of the annulus.

We've shown that $t(r) \ge t(s)$ when $r < s$. This same argument also showed that if $t(r) = |a_n|$ then $t(s') = t(r) = a_n$ whenever $s' > $r (we already know it can't be less than $|a_n|$, and it can't be more than $|a_n|$ by the reasoning above). So, if $t(r) = |a_n|$ then $t(s') = |a_n|$ whenever $s' \ge r$. Then $\displaystyle \frac{p(z)}{z^n}$ is constant on $|z| \ge r$ (since modulus reaches its maximum on interior points of *some* annulus).

Finally, suppose $t(r) \gt |a_n|$ and $t(r) = t(s)$ for $r \lt s$. Then for some $R > s > r$, $t(R) < t(s)$, and so the maximum modulus of $\displaystyle \frac{p(z)}{z^n}$ on the annulus $r |\le |z| \le R$ occurs on $|z| = r$. But in this case as well there is in interior point on $|z| = s$ where the maximum modulus is attained. This shows that $\displaystyle \frac{p(z)}{z^n}$ is in fact constant - which is in fact a contradiction, since then we couldn't have $t(R) < t(r)$.

So, whenever $t(s) = t(r)$ we wind up with $\displaystyle \frac{p(z)}{z^n} = K$ a constant. Taking the limit as $z \to \infty$ shows that $K = a_n$.